# Asynchronous task isn't being asynchronous

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I'm developing a chat application in Android and have run into a massive problem. I need a thread to constantly run in the background (polling a server), and have attached it to my main process via a Handle.

The main problem is: As long as this background thread is running, the foreground one grinds to a complete halt!

Here is an incomplete chunk of code (because the full version is much longer/uglier)...

```
public class ChatActivity extends Activity {
    ...

    private Thread chatUpdateTask;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        ...

        chatUpdateTask = new ChatUpdateTask(handler);
        chatUpdateTask.start();
    }

    public void updateChat(JSONObject json) {
        // ...
        // Updates the chat display
    }


    // Define the Handler that receives messages from the thread and update the progress
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // Get json from the sent Message and display it
            updateChat(json);
        }
    };

    public class ChatUpdateTask extends Thread {
        Handler mHandler;   // for handling things outside of the thread.

        public ChatUpdateTask(Handler h) {
            mHandler = h;               // When creating, make sure we request one!
        }//myTask

        @Override
        public void start() {
            while(mState==STATE_RUNNING) {

                // ...
                // Send message to handler here

                Thread.sleep(500);  // pause on completion

            }//wend
        }//end start

        /* sets the current state for the thread,
         * used to stop the thread */
        public void setState(int state) {
            mState = state;
        }//end setState


        public JSONObject getChatMessages() {
            // ... call server, return messages (could take up to 50 seconds to execute; 
            // server only returns messages when there are new ones
            return json;
        }
    }//end class myTask


}
```

Comment: Use an AsyncTask. Much easier to do and it works wonders.

Comment: My only problem with the AsyncTask (besides not playing with it enough) is that I don't want this task to end unless it's told to end by the calling process...

Otherwise, we might have a winner here. I played with it once but there's so much that could have gone wrong, I probably missed it altogether.

Comment: AsyncTask can run forever so long as you never leave `doInBackground`.  You'd have to end it the same way you'd end a Java thread.

Comment: MFW somebody downvotes without ever giving a reason for downvoting...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're overriding `start()`.  Threads run in their `run()` method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: Wow. I am so thick sometimes. This works, perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't even notice this either. Nicely spotted.